# Linear algebra proof

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $\vec{v}_1 ,\vec{v}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Suppose that $\vec{p}_1$ is the projection of $\vec{v}_1$ onto $W$ and $\vec{p}_2$ is the projection of $\vec{v}_2$ onto $W$. What is the projection of $\vec{v}_1+\vec{v}_2$ onto $W$?

I was thinking of making $\{\vec{u}_1,\cdots,\vec{u}_n\}$ an orthonormal basis for $W$ and manipulating that. I don't have a good idea where to start here. I've tried a few different ways. Any hints?

Comment: is the projection operator linear?

Comment: Projection is a scalar.

Comment: Yes--the projection is linear (or a scalar, depending on how you phrase it). Perhaps I can simply take each element in $\vec{v}_1$ and $\vec{v}_2$ and find the projection of their union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do things that way.  Suppose $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ is such a basis.  We calculate the projection of $v_1 + v_2$ as
$$
P_W(v_1 + v_2) = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle v_1+v_2,u_i \rangle u_i
$$
Now, how can we "split up" this sum?

Comment: a small typo $\langle v_1+v_2,u_i \rangle u_i$. You missed the vector $u_i$.

Comment: @AnuragA fixed, thanks.

Comment: This is simply $\sum \langle v_1,u_i \rangle u_i + \langle v_2,u_i \rangle u_i$. Therefore, it appears that $P_{v_1+v_2} = P_{v_1} + P_{v_2}$. Is this correct?

Comment: @user10445 yes, that's right.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\pi:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow W$ be the projection operator (note it is a linear operator). Then $\pi^2=\pi$. You are given that
\begin{align*}
\pi(v_1)&=p_1\\
\pi(v_2)&=p_2.
\end{align*}
Then 
$$\pi(v_1+v_2) =\pi(v_1)+\pi(v_2)=p_1+p_2.$$